# Access to the pixel value of a Mat using the JavaCV API

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, mat

I have recently switched from the OpenCV C++ API to JavaCV and I'm trying to perform a basic operation, such as iterating over a Mat. I'm trying to access the pixel value of the Mat, but I can't seem to find a way, and the JavaCV project is short on documentation. Using the OpenCV C++ API, I used to access the pixel value of a Mat by using the `.at()` method.

The Mat is loaded as CV_8UC1 Mat (greyscale), as you can see in the code below, and I would like to print/use the 0-255 value of the pixels.

```
    Mat image = imread("images/Text00.png", CV_8UC1);

    // Make sure it was successfully loaded.
    if (image == null) {
        System.out.println("Image not found!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println(image.rows());
    System.out.println(image.cols());

    for (int y = 0; y < image.rows(); y++) {

        for (int x = 0; x < image.cols(); x++) {

            // How to print the 0 to 255 value of each pixel in the Mat image.
        }
    }
```

Similar but not applicable answers:

- [How to iterate through a cvMat matrix in JavaCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641292/how-to-iterate-through-a-cvmat-matrix-in-javacv) (outdated, applicable to CvMat)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On this, [seemingly unrelated thread](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/35) on the JavaCV GitHub discussion, I found the answer to my question after 1 day of googling. Pleace notice that there may be other, more efficient ways to do this, but this is the only way I found at the moment.
The solution is the represented by the new **"indexer" package** provided by JavaCV (see [this](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/commit/4d8dc9d8b244b79ca3c9d9355e476f028f3f36f9) and [this](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/commit/ab8bde373733190fe204a3bb8d1837fbb7c62b4f) for more details).

Its usage is pretty straightforward: after declaring something like `DoubleIndexer idx = Mat.createIndexer()` you can call `idx.get(i, j)` to get the elements of the matrix more easily.

Here is my updated code (as you can see, I used a UByteBufferIndexer, since my Mat is a CV_8UC1 Mat):

```
    Mat image = imread("images/Text00.png", CV_8UC1);

    // Make sure it was successfully loaded.
    if (image == null) {
        System.out.println("Image not found!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    UByteBufferIndexer sI = image.createIndexer();

    for (int y = 0; y < image.rows(); y++) {

        for (int x = 0; x < image.cols(); x++) {

            System.out.println( sI.get(y, x) );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here it shows `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bytedeco.javacpp.indexer.UByteRawIndexer cannot be cast to org.bytedeco.javacpp.indexer.UByteBufferIndexer`, but it works fine after changing `UByteBufferIndexer` into `UByteRawIndexer`. Thanks!